# Dialog for SpaceResorts after selecting a resort

Tags: bixby

I would like to have Bixby read out the description after selecting a resort. Since the description is not shown when all resorts are being displayed, it'd be nice to have the description dialog after selecting a resort.

I am trying to get the dialog for when result == 1. I have tried to create a dialog to match ViewAll from-property SpaceResort, but still have not been able to get any custom dialog.

```
result-view {
  match {
    ViewAll(all) {
      from-property {
        SpaceResort (result)
      }
    }
  }

  message {
    template-macro (SPACE_RESORT_RESULT) {
      param (result) {expression (result)}
    }
  }

  render {
    if (size(result) > 1) {
      list-of (result) {
        where-each (item) {
          layout-macro (space-resort-summary) {
            param (spaceResort) {
              expression(item)
            }
          }
        }
 layout
        highlights {
          select(pick) {
            label {
              template-macro (HIGHLIGHT_LABEL_BY_PREFERENCES)
            }
            layout-macro (space-resort-highlight) {
              param (spaceResort) {
                expression(pick)
              }
            }
            order-by {
              sorting (pick) {
                by-preferences
              }
            }
          }
          select(pick) {
            label("#{raw(pick.highlight)}")
            layout-macro (space-resort-highlight) {
              param (spaceResort) {
                expression(pick)
              }
            }
            filter-by (exists(pick.highlight))
          }
          select(pick) {
            label("#{raw(pick.highlight)}")
            layout-macro (space-resort-highlight) {
              param (spaceResort) {
                expression(pick)
              }
            }
            filter-by (exists(pick.highlight))
          }
          select(pick) {
            label("#{raw(pick.highlight)}")
            layout-macro (space-resort-highlight) {
              param (spaceResort) {
                expression(pick)
              }
            }
            filter-by (exists(pick.highlight))
          }
        }
      }
    } else-if (size(result) == 1) {
      layout-macro (space-resort-details) {
        param (spaceResort) {
          expression (result)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  conversation-drivers {
    if ("size(result) == 1") {
      conversation-driver {
        template-macro (MakeReservation)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `resources/en/dialogs/` and created a dialog called `selected_planet.dialog.bxb`.

Create a dialog with this code:

```
dialog (Result) {
  match: SpaceResort (this)

  template("You selected this planet!.") {
    speech ("#{value(this.description)}")
  }
}
```

The description will now be read out loud by Bixby.

**To test this:**
Say `"Give me a space resort near mars"` and select one of the options that appear.

Comment: I have tried your example, but it still doesn't work. When I use "Give me a space resort near mars" and select a resort, Bixby does not say anything.

Comment: Here's some steps you can do to problem solve that:  1) Uninstall and reinstall Bixby to determine that you have the latest version.  2) Re-clone the Space Resort Capsule from the Bixby Github page and try creating the dialog again. 3) Check to make sure the "Toggle speech to output" button is selected in the simulator. 4)Try running the test 2-3 times. Sometimes it can take a few seconds for Bixby to apply the updates depending on your internet connection.